# External Sensor interfaced with MSP430

Tags: msp430, zigbee

I have interfaced a humidity sensor with MSP430F2274 on pin P2_2 (Kit CC2530 ZNP) and using the following code to read the output voltage from the sensor. But it doesn't seem to be working.
I am getting a different value each time and it's way off the actual output from the sensor. I have a separate module which takes care of the clock and timers. The Kit has on-board Light and temperature sensors which seem to work perfectly fine. Could you please have a look?

```
getHumidity()
{
  int result, volt;

  ADC10CTL0 &= ~ENC;
  ADC10CTL0 &= ~ADC10ON;

  // P2.2 -> Humidity Sensor - A2

 P2DIR &= ~0x04; 
 P2SEL &= ~0x04; 

 ADC10AE0 |= 0x04; 
 ADC10AE1 = 0x00; 

 ADC10CTL0 = SREF_1 + ADC10SHT_3 + REFON + ADC10ON + ADC10IE + REF2_5V;
 ADC10CTL1 = INCH_2 + ADC10DIV_3; // Input Selct and Clock Div

 ADC10CTL0 |= ENC + ADC10SC; // Start to sample


 while(ADC10CTL1 & ADC10BUSY); 
 result = ADC10MEM; // Store Result


 volt=(int)((result*2500.00)/1023.00);

 ADC10AE0 = 0; // Reset Selection Bits
 ADC10AE1 = 0;

 ADC10CTL0 &= ~ENC;    
 ADC10CTL0 &= ~(REFON + ADC10ON);

 return volt; // Return Result      
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a known voltage (like from a small battery) onto the input and confirming this reading is also not working. BTW the code, as presented looks a complete mess - try formatting it by editing the question.

Comment: @Andyaka: Thanks for the reply. I tried printing the battery voltage using INCH_11 and I am getting the exact battery voltage value from ADC10MEM. The temperature and light sensors which are present on board are also giving the exact values. I am not sure why the external humidity sensor is not working

Comment: @megha if three different sensors are working with the same code, it's not the code or the mcu that's the problem. Maybe the humidity sensor is bad. Can you test a different one? Do you have a datasheet for it?

Comment: @Passerby: Thanks for the quick response. I ordered some new Humidity sensors and I am facing the same problem with them too. The other sensors (light, temperature) are on the kit itself but the Humidity sensor is externally soldered to the kit.The problem could be with my pin setup (P2DIR, P2SEL, ADC10AE0).

Comment: @megha part number?

Comment: @Passerby: Humidity sensor I am using is Honeywell Board Mount Humidity sensors, HIH-5030-001S and the kit with which I am interfacing these sensors is CC2530 ZNP ZDK Mini Kit which also has MSP430 processor

Comment: @megha do you have a decoupling cap on the sensor?

Comment: @Passerby I am not sure how to check that. I am a computer science student. The sensor is producing correct output voltage which is constant, have checked with multimeter.  This constant voltage when supplied to the input of A/D converter produces values with a lot of fluctuation.The value almost seem random.

Comment: A decoupling capacitor is a small capacitor, typically 0.1uF or 100nF (same thing), close to the VCC and GND pins of the sensor. And a multimeter is a fairly slow thing sometimes, so you won't see what could be happening is that the signal changes very fast. Faster than the multimeter can update, so it averages it out. But the microcontroller is faster, so it sees the problem. You could do two things. One, take multiple samples with the ADC, and take the average, or use an oscilliscope to see what the signal really looks like.